# How to clone a list within itself?

Tags: python, list

suppose I have a list

```
a = [1,2,4,5]
```

I want to create another list b which clones a and adds it 3 times. So b is expected to be

```
b = [1,2,4,5,1,2,4,5,1,2,4,5]
```

How do I do this easily?
Methods using pandas or numpy is also welcome.

Comment: The * operator works on lists, but only if they are primitives.

Comment: `b = 3 * a` works for this

Comment: @Mous no, it *always* works and Python doesn't have "primitives".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it will duplicate objects. This behaviour can lead to bugs, which is why I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#just use the * operator
b=a*3
```